# Matching future types

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I am attempting to work with futures to look up asynchronously look up a value. If that value exists I want to return it and if it does not I want to create it.

```
// A network will be created unless one already exists with this name
pub fn build_network(name: &'static str) {
    let docker = Docker::new();

    // Get a list of networks
    let fut = docker
        .networks()
        .list(&Default::default())
        .and_then(move |networks| {
            // Check if a network with the given name exists  
            let network = networks.iter().find(|n| n.name == name);

            match network {
                // Pass on network
                Some(net) => future::ok(net.id),
                // Create a new network
                None => {
                    let docker = Docker::new();
                    docker
                        .networks()
                        .create(&NetworkCreateOptions::builder(name).driver("bridge").build())
                        .map(|new_net| new_net.id)

                }
            }
        })
        .map(move |net| {
            println!("{:#?}", net);
        })
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Error: {}", e));

    tokio::run(fut);
}
```

It looks like there is a type mismatch in my match expression. I am trying to make sure each arm contains a future for a shiplift network struct, but it looks like I'm not quite getting it.

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
   --> src/up/mod.rs:168:13
    |
168 | /             match network {
169 | |                 // Pass on network
170 | |                 Some(net) => future::ok(net.id),
171 | |                 // Create a new network
...   |
178 | |                 }
179 | |             }
    | |_____________^ expected struct `futures::FutureResult`, found struct `futures::Map`
    |
    = note: expected type `futures::FutureResult<std::string::String, _>`
               found type `futures::Map<impl futures::Future, [closure@src/up/mod.rs:177:30: 177:50]>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
   --> src/up/mod.rs:172:25
    |
172 |                   None => {
    |  _________________________^
173 | |                     let docker = Docker::new();
174 | |                     docker
175 | |                         .networks()
176 | |                         .create(&NetworkCreateOptions::builder(name).driver("bridge").build())
177 | |                         .map(|new_net| new_net.id)
178 | |                 }
    | |_________________^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clearest mistake is the `;` at the end of the `None` branch.  A semicolon always discards the value of the previous expression, and a block ending with a semicolon has type `()` (assuming the end is reachable).

After removing the `;`, you’ll see that the types still don’t match.  The `Some` branch has type `FutureResult<&NetworkDetails>`, while the `None` branch now has type `impl Future<Item = NetworkCreateInfo>`.  I’m not sure what you’re trying to do here, since even the base `NetworkDetails` and `NetworkCreateInfo` types are incompatible.  You’ll need to figure out what type you want and how to get the same type in both branches.

Edit for updated question: Okay, you want to get a `String` out of both branches.  You have two different types that both implement the `Future<Item = String>` trait, and you need both branches to be of the same type.  This is exactly the purpose of [`future::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/future/enum.Either.html).  Simply wrap one branch in `Either::A` and the other branch in `Either::B`.

After that, you’ll also find a trivial borrowing problem in the first branch: you’ll need to copy the string with `net.id.clone()`.

Comment: I have edited the question based on this. Considering `NetworkDetails` and `NetworkCreateInfo` are not types I think the best option is to return the network id as a `&str`.